# Why does this circuit stop breaking down with a stronger flyback diode?

Tags: temperature, led-driver, flyback

On a PCBA, I am using a LED driver to drive a high-power LED. Here is the schematics:

[image]

- V_IN = 16 V
- R_OSC is set so that the gate of the MOSFET is controlled at 150 kHz
- R_CS is set so that the current in the LED is 1.5 A
- Q1 = STT6N3LLH6 (V_DS = 30 V, I_DS = 6 A)
- L1 = SDR1105-150ML (I_RMS = 3.5 A, I_SAT = 8 A)
- D1 = PMEG3050EP,115 (I = 5 A, V = 30 V)

I am experiencing something strange. If I manually raise the temperature of the circuit with a hot air station, the diode and/or the transistor always break down (short circuit) at approx. 80°C. If I replace D1 with PMEG4030EP,115 (I = 3 A, V = 40 V), I can raise the temperature to 130°C and it still works.

Looking at the signals with a scope, I was not able to detect any change while the temperature is rising. Here are the signals:

- At the gate :
  [image]
- At R_CS:
  [image]
- At the cathode of the LED:
  [image]

The only two differences between the diodes are:

- The reverse voltage (30 -> 40 V)
- The reverse current (2.6 mA -> 35 uA)

I am glad that the new diode resolves the temperature breakdown, but I would like to understand why. Do you have an idea?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you double check if you mentioned the correct part where you mention that replacing it with PMEG4030EP, that part is a 40V part, while your text says it is a 30V part

Comment: L1: did you mean SDR1105-150ML (15uH 52mΩ) (see: https://www.bourns.com/docs/product-datasheets/sdr1105.pdf )? 3rd scope shot: did you mean LED cathode? Notice diode capacitances differ, and leakage at high voltage and temperature may also differ. Can you measure transistor and diode body temperatures under the elevated ambient condition? (Try a heated box instead of hot air: less turbulence, more component temp rise.)

Comment: @Ferrybig : you are right I made it more clear

Comment: @TimWilliams : I have edited the question. The body temperatures of all the components was about 80 degrees (they are grouped together)

Comment: Don't assume they're all the same temperature because they're "grouped together". You need an IR camera (may need a magnifier / macro lens on it to resolve the SMT chips), or very small thermocouple glued/taped to the device(s), to measure the body temperature in a representative manner.

Comment: I was indeed measuring the temperature with a thermal camera. The components were at the same temperature +- 5°C

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *If I replace D1 with PMEG4030EP,115 (I = 3 A, V = 40 V), I can raise
> the temperature to 130 °C and it still works. I am glad that the new diode resolves the temperature breakdown, but I would like to understand why.*
>
> *Do you have an idea?**

It's quite likely to be reverse current problems as the temperature rises. Here's a side-by-side comparison of the [PMEG3050](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/PMEG3050EP.pdf) and the [PMEG4030](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/PMEG4030EP.pdf) diodes: -

[image]

The reverse leakage current at higher temperatures can get high on Schottky diodes and, the 3050 is massively nastier than the 4030 in this respect. I've used +85 °C for the junction temperature and compared it with 25 °C for both devices.

> *If I manually raise the temperature of the circuit with a hot air
> station, the diode and/or the transistor always break down (short
> circuit) at approx. 80°C.*

In an ambient of 80 °C the junction might be up at 125 °C and the 3050 will be conducting about 300 mA when reverse biased. On a supply of 16 volts, that's a power dissipation of ~5 watts and it'll burn then fail short circuit and, then the switching transistor fails.

Comment: What are the consequences of leakage current in the diode in such a configuration ?

Comment: Looking at these too right now and I noticed that the reverse currents in general are very different. PMEG3050 (VR = 30 V; Tj = 25 °C) 2.6mA typical. Whereas PMEG4030 (VR = 40 V; Tj = 25 °C) has it as 25uA typical. Also they have different thermal resistance from junction to solder point, though I'm not sure if that matters depending on how the board is heated (hot air gun vs heat from the expected current).

Comment: @uz3il while the diode is supposedly non-conducting (the inductor charge phase) it might be conducting actually 1 mA at 25 degC and 40 mA at 85 degC (3050). Compare that to the 4030 (10 uA and 800 uA) <-- a massive difference.

Comment: @Andyaka : Thank you, your answer is very clear. I think that's precisely the problem !